# FIFO calculation in php (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two data tables stock_incomes, stock_outcomes and stock_outcomes_fifo (the one I insert pre-calculated data):

stock_incomes (stores leftovers data)

```
id| Levtv
-----------
7 | 100
8 | 250
9 | 350
```

stock_outcomes (here is the point)

```
id| Quantity
--------------
1 |  150*
```

I have no problem when stock_outcomes.Quantity is less than 100 (min(Id) from stock_incomes, please see my code below) but I have no idea what code to write I could get calculations if outcome is >100. In my example I used 150 and I would like to get data in next table as:

stock_outcomes_fifo (the one I wish to insert pre-calculated data from the previous two tables)

```
id| IncomeId| OutcomeId| OutcomePart| Leftv
---------------------------------------------
1 |    7    |     1    |     100    |  0
2 |    8    |     1    |      50    |  200
```

Here is my code with question inside (see last part of the code):

```
<?php
include_once("config.inc.php");
include_once("db.class.php");

// stock_outcomes
$db = new db($host, $database, $user, $passwd);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_outcomes WHERE Id = '1'";
$mas = $db->get_array($sql);

if($mas) {
    foreach ($mas as $k => $v) {
           $OutcomeId = $mas[$k]['Id'];
           $OutcomeQuantity = $mas[$k]['Quantity'];
    }
}

// stock_incomes
$sql = "select * from stock_incomes where Id = (select min(Id) from stock_incomes where Leftv > 0)";
$mas = $db->get_array($sql);

if($mas) {
    foreach ($mas as $k => $v) {
        $IncomeId = $mas[$k]['Id'];
        $IncomeLeftv = $mas[$k]['Leftv'];
    }
}

// insert into stock_outcomes_fifo

if ($OutcomeQuantity <= $IncomeLeftv) { 
    $OutcomePart = $OutcomeQuantity;
    $FifoLeftv = $IncomeLeftv - $OutcomeQuantity;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stock_outcomes_fifo` (IncomeId,OutcomeId,OutcomePart,Leftv) VALUES ($IncomeId, $OutcomeId, $OutcomePart, $FifoLeftv)");
}

if ($OutcomeQuantity > $IncomeLeftv) {
    // I have no idea what php function to use in this case... please give me direction, thank you...
}
?>
```

Comment: I edited your post to make the code more readable, but your question is still somewhat unclear. Could you take another look at your question and see if you can reword it to make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

The question has been solved, here is the final working code in case someone might need it:

```
<?php
include_once("config.inc.php");
include_once("db.class.php");

// stock_outcomes
$db = new db($host, $database, $user, $passwd);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_outcomes WHERE Id = '1'";
$mas = $db->get_array($sql);

if($mas){
    foreach ($mas as $k=>$v) {
           $OutcomeId=$mas[$k]['Id'];
           $OutcomeBarCode=$mas[$k]['BarCode'];
           $OutcomeQuantity=$mas[$k]['Quantity']; 
    }
}

/* - Start code */
if ($OutcomeQuantity > 0) {
$sql = "select * from stock_incomes where Leftv > 0 order by id asc";
$mas = $db->get_array($sql);

if ($mas) {
    //filing stock_outcomes_fifo 
        foreach ($mas as $k=>$v) {
        $IncomeId = $mas[$k]['Id'];
        $IncomeQuantity = $mas[$k]['Quantity'];
        $IncomeUnitPrice = $mas[$k]['UnitPrice'];
        $IncomeLeftv = $mas[$k]['Leftv'];

        $OutcomePart = min($OutcomeQuantity, $IncomeLeftv);
        $FifoLeftv = $IncomeLeftv - $OutcomePart; 
        $FifoCost = $IncomeUnitPrice * $OutcomePart;

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stock_outcomes_fifo` (BarCode,IncomeId,OutcomeId,OutcomePart,UnitPrice,Leftv,Cost) VALUES ($OutcomeBarCode, $IncomeId, $OutcomeId, $OutcomePart, $IncomeUnitPrice, $FifoLeftv, $FifoCost)");          
        mysql_query("UPDATE `stock_incomes` SET Leftv = ".$FifoLeftv." WHERE Id = ".$IncomeId);

        $OutcomeQuantity -= $OutcomePart;
        if ($OutcomeQuantity <= 0) break;
    }

    $OutcomeCostQuery = "select sum(Cost) as summ from stock_outcomes_fifo where OutcomeId = ".$OutcomeId."";
    $OutcomeCost = mysql_query($OutcomeCostQuery);
    $OutcomeCostResult = mysql_fetch_array($OutcomeCost);        
    mysql_query("UPDATE `stock_outcomes` SET Cost = ".$OutcomeCostResult["summ"]." WHERE Id = ".$OutcomeId."");
}
} /* - Finish code */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please help me let me explain with this..... 
purchase table 
id    purchase_id     product_id    qty    net_unit_cost    created_at
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1               1          10         10           2022-10-10 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2        2               1          20         12           2022-10-10 

Sale table 
sale_id    product_id     qty     net_unit_price      created_at 
1             1           11            15            2022-10-10 

in this, if i sold '11' units then how can i subtract from the rows to get remaining units? i've to subtract '10' units from first row and '1' unit from second row...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).